# How to use convolutional neural nets on 'cylindrical images'

Tags: machine-learning, keras

Suppose I have a data-set of images that 'live on a cylinder' (for example, if my images were taken by panorama shots that wrap around onto themselves). How would I modify a convolutional neural network to take this into account? A few simple 'hacks' I can imagine performing (and why I consider them not as full solutions):

- Currently, I am representing the cylindrical image as a rectangular image (with a cut along the cylinder), and then 'cylindrically padding' by taking the leftmost few columns and adding them to the right:
  [image]
  the idea being that now the network has access to the information that the star is near the 1, but this doesn't 'actually work' in my mind, like it might work for the first convolutional layer, but if I have multiple layers it seems that I actually want my network architecture to reflect the cylindrical symmetry
- Do the same rectangular representation as above, but augment my data-set by taking each image and rotating it about the cylindrical axis pixel by pixel. Again, this feels like a hack and not a real solution

I'm using Keras, and am mostly interested in 'practical solutions', I would have thought Keras would have an option to deal with this situation (maybe like cylindrical padding or something) but I can't find any. The next idea I had in my mind was to write my own Keras layers to deal with this problem (modifying the existing convolutional/pooling layers) but I'm not sure how to start

Comment: I think your solution as depicted makes sense. See a recent relevant pytorch discussion on this exact topic: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6124 and possible solution: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/3858

Comment: Perhaps we can use $$R \times S^1 \approx R^2 \backslash \{0\}$$

Answer (score 0):

I also need to solve the problem and came up with a solution. However, I only know how to code it up in `PyTorch`. I will include my code here and then explain why I think it may work.

```py
class CylConv1d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, 
                 length,
                 in_channels, 
                 out_channels, 
                 kernel_size, 
                 stride = 1, 
                 dilation = 1, 
                 **kwargs):

        super().__init__()

        # Convolution window size calculated from kernel and dilation
        window_size = (kernel_size - 1) * dilation + 1
        
        # The front-padding size is the lesser half of the window size
        self.f_pad = window_size // 2
        # The after-padding size is to ensure the last convolution 
        # has enough elements to be carried out.
        self.a_pad = max(0, window_size - 1 - self.f_pad - (length - 1) % stride)
        
        # After padding is done (in forward)
        # we only need to run a normal convolution without padding
        self.conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels, 
                              out_channels, 
                              kernel_size, 
                              stride = stride, 
                              padding = 0, 
                              dilation = dilation,
                              **kwargs)
        
    def forward(self, data):
        """
        Input
        =========
        data: (batch_size, in_channels, length)
        """
        batch_size, in_channels, _ = data.shape
        
        f_pad_data = torch.zeros(batch_size, in_channels, 0)
        a_pad_data = torch.zeros(batch_size, in_channels, 0)
        if self.f_pad > 0:
            f_pad_data = data[..., -self.f_pad:]
        if self.a_pad > 0:
            a_pad_data = data[..., :self.a_pad]
        
        data_padded = torch.concat([f_pad_data, data, a_pad_data], axis=-1)
        return self.conv(data_padded)
```

The idea is straightforward: we pad the front of the array with the end of the array and pad the end of the array with the front of the array. The trickier question is how much we should pad. I am actually not 100% sure whether my approach is correct, so please point out my mistake and help me improve. My approach is as follows. Denote:

- the kernel size by `f`, and
- the dilation by `d`

then we can calculate the convolution window size is `w = (f - 1)(d - 1) + f`. We can pad the front of the array by half this window size (`w // 2` in `Python` notation).

To calculate how much we need to pad at the end of the array, denote

- the length by `n`, and
- the stride by `s`,

then the total number of convolutions equals `(n - 1) // s + 1`, and the last convolution starts with the element with index

> `-(w // 2) + s((n - 1) // s)`

and hence the index of the last element in this last convolution should be

> `-(w // 2) + s((n - 1) // s) + w - 1`.

However, since our array ends at index `n - 1`, we know that we need to pad the end with

> `-(w // 2) + s((n - 1) // s) + w - 1 - (n - 1) = w - 1 - (w // 2) + (n - 1) mod s`

elements from the front of the array.

Finally, since we will manually cut the array and glue them to the correct place `forward` function, we only need to run a convolution with no padding at all.